# Sitecore - setting background-image a div to a CMS value

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8

I've been try to add the background image of a div to a value from Sitecore (8.0) in C# MVC using the code

```
<div style="background-image: url({Model.MyImage.Src})>
```

Where MyImage is of type Image as returned by GlassView

This is returning html such as

```
<div style="background-image: url(/~/media/myFolders/myImage.ashx)">
```

This image isnt being displayed when the page is rendered- although the url resolves when entered into the browser's address bar so it must be an issue with the .ashx extension as a background image for a div.

I also tried using Sitecore.Resources.Media.MediaManager.GetMediaUrl(mediaItem) but this also returned me the ashx which couldn't be resolved!

Comment: Add single quotes around it. 

url('{Model.MyImage.Src}')

Should make this

url('/~/media/myFolders/myImage.ashx')

Comment: Doh! How did I miss that.. Please add it as an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `background-image: url('@Model.Image.Src')`. While your example doesn't show it, you most likely have spaces in your folder or file name, which requires single or double quotes.

Answer (score 1):

Add single quotes around it.

```
url('{Model.MyImage.Src}')
```

Should make this

```
url('/~/media/myFolders/myImage.ashx')
```

Answer (score 0):

for my case sitecore 8.2 stop working below code because of style attribute

I have replaced style attribute with img tag and start working

```
<span><img src="@item.GetImageUrl("MyImage")" alt="" class="icon" /></span>
```